# ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE when hitting client connection endpoint

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I have created a service fabric service application with a stateless service. I have deployed it in Azure service fabric cluster.

Endpoint in ServiceManifest.xml is

```
<Endpoint Name="WebEndpoint" Protocol="http" Port="80" Type="Input"/>
```

When I check service fabric explorer, it shows everything working properly. But when I hit client connection endpoint `cluster_name.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:19000` from browser, it returns `ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE`.

When checked in fiddler it shows `HTTP/1.0 200 This buggy server did not return headers`.

I have followed [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services) throughout except step 3 & 4.

How do I get valid response on client connection endpoint when hit through browser?

---

Update:

I have published https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started/tree/vs2015 on localhost as well as Azure Service Fabric Cluster.

Endpoint on localhost service fabric cluster : http://localhost:8081/

Endpoint on Azure service fabric cluster : http://10.0.0.4:8081/

[image]

I get the above shown screen on localhost endpoint but `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` for the other one. What settings am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 19000 is Service Fabric's default cluster management port.

Assuming you have port 80 forwarded in your load balancer, and open on appropriate nodes, you should be able to access your site on the above url but at port 80.

Comment: Hey Mardoxx, updated the question to explain in an easier way. Can you please update the answer?

Comment: htrp://cluster_name.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:80 or 8081 for the other sample assuming your LB is set up properly

Comment: I have kept the default settings for LB. What settings must be done to say 'LB is set up properly'?

Comment: What it says in the guide, forward an external port to internal one on your nodes, e.g. 80 external to 80 internal

Comment: The problem was solved by adding port 8081 as custom endpoint port while creating a cluster though I am not sure if it is the right way to do so. I am now in search of workaround that does not require to add port 8081 as custom endpoint.